# Is there a plugin that will completely remove the category system?

Tags: categories

I have no use in categorizing/tagging my posts with anything, at all, and it doesn't look very good to have every post say "filed under: uncategorized."

Is there any plugin to do this, or do I need to do some manual editing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why hack apart what's already there? If you remove the built in taxonomies, you'll end up **creating hiccups** in core code that expect them to be there!

You're **much** better off just editing your theme file(s), or filtering out categories on the front-end (ask if you need help on that).

For example, in your theme's `index.php` and `single.php`, you might have something like;

```
filed under: <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>.
```

Just remove it and you're done!

Comment: +1 for not affecting the WordPress core. It's much easier to do things at the presentation level.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy. [Here's a **Plugin**](https://gist.github.com/870890) that will allow you to do the same to all `_builtin` taxonomies. You will have to uncomment if you want to get some feedback. The second function shows the result in your `wp_footer()` hook at a priority of 999. It will only show if you got `WP_DEBUG` turned on, so no reports in live systems :)

You just have to put it into the `functions.php` file of your theme or upload it as plugin. The meta box on post edit screen disappears magically. Also: tested and works.

Comment: That's kind of cool!  Still would require a bit of a template edit correct?  Like to get rid of the 'Posted in' text or whatever that may exist?

Comment: See my updated answer. And about templates: Yes, you'll have to remove/uncomment the output in your templates. Just do some Voodoo magic ;)

Comment: @kaiser, nice solution, but I wouldn't recommend removing built-in taxes. WordPress (as of 3.1) still makes assumptions about their existence, and you might end up causing problems down the line.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: I missunderstood slightly. I thought it was about how to get it rid completely (for whatever reason). I also thought about posting how to remove the meta box from post edit screen.

Comment: That's fair enough, but I would advise the OP to make the changes on the front-end (I can't see the harm in having them in the admin, even if they're not being used).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: Absolutely. This would a) be the better solution for this case and b) it's not necassary to remove anything. As i said: i only missunderstood the Q. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the post side, under screen options I believe you can hide the selection menus.  Just for personal/cosmetic reason.  Might as well hide them if you arent using them

As for removing it from displaying you will need to do some form of editing.

It all depends on your theme though on how to do it.  You could simply delete the_category and the_tags (with surrounding text) from some themes in all the templates (index.php, single.php, archive,.php, etc)

In a theme like twentyten, you would need to edit the twentyten_posted_in function from a child theme
http://go.rvoodoo.com/WPchild
is an article I wrote about child themes

It's hard to give real specific info without knowing the theme, or seeing the underlying code, but these are general tips

You may also be able to simply hide things if your cats and tags have classes around the using display:none in your css to target them